# How can I use the CREATE command to create a objects that are numeric?

Tags: sql-server

How can I use the CREATE command to create an object that is numeric? Are there any issues with have objects that are numeric?

Trying to create the follow objects with numeric names, (CREATE LOGIN 1000 ... fails, CREATE LOGIN a1000 ... works)

- SCHEMA
- LOGIN
- USER
- TABLE

Comment: Delimiters will allow this, but it's a dangerous practice since if the delimiter is omitted the resulting statement might be syntactically valid, but wrong. `select [1000] from myTable` is not the same as `select 1000 from myTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `1000` in square brackets `[1000]`, e.g.

```
create schema [1000]
```

You can put any identifier in square brackets, even those that are not normally allowed, e.g. ones containing spaces, etc.